# Powershell to move N amount of files if target is empty only

Tags: powershell, copy, parent-child, move

I am attempting to slowly move files into a processing directory. I have a source directory with 700,000 files in it. I slowly want to move them over to a target directory 5,000 files at a time. I only want to move the 5,000 though if the target is empty. I have found the below script that moves files over to a target, but it creates subdirectories. I am just attempting to do a straight move (cut and paste) like for like from one folder to another. I dont want it to move the 5000 though if the target has even 1 file in it.  Do I just need to get the count of the target and only enact if it  equals 0? Wasnt sure how to edit the below to stop creating subfolders, too.

```
$filesperfolder = 5000     # or should that be: Get-Random -Maximum 5000 -Minimum 1
$sourcePath     = 'D:\source'
$destPath       = 'E:\Dest'
$fileIndex = $folderNum = 0

# append -Filter '*.jpg' if you only want to move .jpg files
$sourceFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File)
$totalCount  = $sourceFiles.Count
# now loop over the files while $totalCount is greater than 0
while ($totalCount -gt 0) {
    $moveCount = [math]::Min($totalCount, $filesperfolder)  # how many are left?
    $folderNum++
    # create the destination folder if it does not already exist
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $destPath -ChildPath $folderNum
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    # loop over the number of files to move using the index of the $sourceFiles array
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $moveCount; $i++) {
        $sourceFiles[$i + $fileIndex] | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder
    }
    $totalCount -= $moveCount  # subtract the number of files already moved
    $fileIndex  += $moveCount  # increase the index for the next iteration
}
```

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem -File -Path $destPath).Length` will give you the number of files in the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the source files the same method you have, but it also uses the same method to check if there are files in the destination (`Get-ChildItem`). If there are no files returned, the process inside the `if` statement is run. This takes the source files you have, selects the first 5000 items, and moves them to the destination location.

```
$filesPerFolder = 5000
$sourcePath     = 'D:\source'
$destPath       = 'E:\Dest'

$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File
if (!(Get-ChildItem -Path $destPath)){
    $sourceFiles | Select-Object -First $filesPerFolder | Move-Item -Destination $destPath
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeremy. That did the trick, too! I saw your response too late and I worked on so many iterations. This is the one I ultimately came up with. If the destination has under 1000 files, drop 5000 more in. Yours is def a bit cleaner!

```
#This is the amount of files you want to move
$filesperfolder = 5000
#This is the path you want to move files FROM
$sourcePath = "\\releaseserver\services$\BatchcmpBDI\Error"
#This is a preprocessing directory in order to flip a release queue
$destPath = "\\releaseserver\services$\BatchcmpBDI\Source"
$destCount =  (Get-ChildItem $destPath).Count
$i = 0;
$folderNum = 1;

#This is the count to look for in destination path. If the amount of files is below this number, invoke the move command in the amount of fileperfolder above
if ($destCount -lt 1000)
{
Get-ChildItem "$sourcePath\*.txt" | % {

if ($i -lt $filesperfolder){
    
    Move-Item $_ ($destPath);

    $i++;
        }

               }
}
```